# "Cannot set property '4' of undefined" of 2D array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-devtools, typeerror

I caught an error of "Cannot set property '4' of undefined" of 2D array in JavaScript code below.

```
    const kLatticeSize = 10;
    const kLatticeHalfSize = 5;
        //A vector notation designating the 4 neighborhoods of the cell on which we put the grains.
    const kDx = [1,0,-1,0];
    const kDy = [0,1,0,-1];

    const LCoord = () => {
        return {x:-1,y:-1}
    }

    const MoveStandard_1Step = (n,ih) => {
        let z_lat =  new Array(kLatticeSize).fill().map(i => new Array(kLatticeSize).fill(ih));
            // models the standard lattice Z^2
        let v_sites = new Array(kLatticeSize).fill().map(i => new Array(kLatticeSize).fill(false));
            // vertices of Z^2 which were visited during the process//which means the neighborhood cells onto which the toppled grains fall.
        v_sites[kLatticeHalfSize][kLatticeHalfSize] = true;

        let to_be_moved = new Array(kLatticeSize).fill().map(i => new Array(kLatticeSize).fill(false));
            // vertices of Z^2 which are already in the walking stack//which means the cell from which a toppling occurs.
        let odometer = new Array(kLatticeSize).fill().map(i => new Array(kLatticeSize).fill(0));
            // total number of topplings of a given vertex of Z^2


        let top = -1;
        let walking = new Array(kLatticeSize*kLatticeSize).fill().map(i => LCoord());
            //"top" is the number of sites which need to topple in the present avalanche.
            //"top = 3" means "3 sites to topple are remaining"
            //When we find a site to topple, we increment "top",
            //and then stack the site into "walking[top]"
            //So,"top" can take  0,1,2,...,(kLatticeSize * kLatticeSize - 1).

        let x = 0, y = 0, lx = 0, ly = 0;
            //(x,y): a site to topple
            //(lx,ly): a next site to topple

        let max_of_top = 0;//max of top in a simulation.
        let n_of_moves = 0;//the number of moves occured on this simulation.

        for(let i = n;i>=0;i--){
            //focusing on the origin
            if(++z_lat[kLatticeHalfSize][kLatticeHalfSize] >= 4){// one grain out of 'n' grains being put on the origin, and evaluating if the height of the origin is bigger or equal to 4(the upper limit value of height with which the cell stays stable.).
                walking[++top].x = kLatticeHalfSize;
                walking[top].y = kLatticeHalfSize;
            }
            console.log(`i:${i}\n`);
                //avalanche
            while(top >= 0){
                n_of_moves += 1;
                console.log(`top=${top}\n`);
                if(max_of_top < top){
                    max_of_top = top;
                }

                    // designate the site which topples.(origin)
                x = walking[top].x;
                y = walking[top].y;

                z_lat[x][y] = z_lat[x][y] - 4;
                if (z_lat[x][y] < 4){
                    top--;
                    to_be_moved[x][y] = false;
                }

                    //designate sites to topple
                    //designate sites onto which a grain falls.
                    //topple.
                for (let k = 0; k < 4; ++k){
                    //designating the neighborhood cells onto which the toppled grains fall.
                    // 'k' denotes a direction out of 4.(k = 0,1,2,3 : right,up,left,down) (refering to "kDx","kDy" on "abel" on "Abel.h")
                    lx = x + kDx[k];
                    ly = y + kDy[k];
                    console.log(`k=${k}:(lx,ly) = (${lx},${ly})`);
                    v_sites[lx][ly] = true;//The falling grain lands on the "true" cell which we designated right above.
                    z_lat[lx][ly]++;//The grain has been piled.

                    if (to_be_moved[lx][ly] == false && z_lat[lx][ly] >= 4){//fires when a toppling successively occurs.(when "avalanche" continues)
                            //(lx,ly) cell is going to be the next one to topple.
                            //Here in this iteration, the integer "top" can take 0,1,2,3 (other than 0)
                        walking[++top].x = lx;
                        walking[top].y = ly;
                        to_be_moved[lx][ly] = true;
                    }
                }

            }


        }

        return z_lat;
    }

    MoveStandard_1Step(30,2);
```

When I try

```
    MoveStandard_1Step(10,2);
```

it works and does not get any error. But,

```
    MoveStandard_1Step(30,2);
```

It gets an error below:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '4' of undefined
at MoveStandard_1Step (:78:24)
at :1:1
MoveStandard_1Step @ VM1627:78
(anonymous) @ VM1667:1

I guess the error might happen when I put a big number as the first argument of the function  "MoveStandard_1Step" .The error happens in this line in a for loop:

```
    v_sites[lx][ly] = true;//The falling grain lands on the "true" cell which we designated right above.
```

Using console.log on Chrome Developer's tool, I found out the number of "for loop" iteration at which the error is happening. It can be seen just by putting the code above into the console on Developer's tool on Chrome.(I cannot show it here because the result lines in console are too long and it gets caught in the limitation on the number of the characters.)

I don't get what is wrong. I don't get what "property '4' of undefined" means. My guess is that the '4' means the index of the 2D array "v_sites" (which is stated at the initial of the function "MoveStandard_1Step"), but it seems to me that the 4th element of "v_sites" is properly defined.
Could you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: sounds like you are accessing an index that is one greater than what exits. `console.log(lx, ly);`

Comment: Exactly. When doing `console.log(lx, ly, v_sites)` I get `10 4 Array(10)` which means we got an array of size 10 and you're trying to access index 10 which is obviously undefined

Comment: Thank you. I forgot JavaScript cannot automatically add new elements when designating non-existing index. (I thought C++ can do it.) The next task seems that I will find the simplest way to add an element of non-existing index designated by (lx,ly) to the 2D array "v_sites".